# How to use Whisper Systems Signal with Python

Tags: python

I know how to send XMPP messages with python, but more of my friends are using signal from whisper systems. How can I use python to send a signal message with the [whisper systems signal protocol](https://github.com/signalapp)?

Comment: Nobody found a solution jet so I used XMPP with OMEMO:

First I activated *remote_control* in Gajim in preferences -> advanced -> advanced config editor. Then restarted Gajim.
Then I used this *gajim-remote* with Python:

    from subprocess import call
    call(gajim-remote send_chat_message to@xmppserver.com 'Hello', shell=True)

Answer (score 1):

There is a python ported library I found recently called libaxolotl - [Github Profile](https://github.com/tgalal/python-axolotl)
Might help you. I'm also just getting started in this domain. So..cheers !!

Comment: @flowerflower If my answer helped you..could you please accept it?